# Uploading file from internet to ssh server

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to download a video from a url, then upload it to an ssh server. The file is a rather large file, 100mb ( http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/100MB.zip ). I've experimented with the pysftp library, but I've only gotten it to download to my computer, and i'm not sure how to make it upload the same file downloaded over ssh. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What operating system is on the computer you're downloading to and uploading from?

Comment: its a windows machine

Comment: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline

Comment: Not using command line using python to make a program to do this.